# How to remove a specific record in firebase database on user action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

I have a database on firebase where data is inserted, divided into two sections (CAT1, CAT2). This is the structure:
`

```
{
  "mPulHwx4C6eTQEwUhhXXTsGb2eq2" : {
    "CAT1" : {
      "-LjMnx_GdJt2qQNlh7ko" : {
        "id" : 238,
        "title" : "FILM1",
        "type" : "movie"
      }
    },
    "CAT2" : {
      "-LjMo4XjVOlUVnvs_iiw" : {
        "id" : 60625,
        "title" : "SERIE1",
        "type" : "tv"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`
How can I delete an item, for example from CAT1, after calling up the entire object via axios?